# How to trigger a state change when hovering over an element

Tags: reactjs

I basically want to trigger a change in a components state when the user is hovering with his mouse over that component.

Since onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave are not properly working under certain conditions (https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6807), is there any alternative?

EDIT:
I think it has something to do with rerendering. When the components are of the same type, but I force a rerender, it causes the same issues.

```
class onHover extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bool: false,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ bool: true })} onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ bool: false })}>
        {
          this.state.bool ? (
            <div key={Math.random()}>[OPTION1] show after onMouseEnter</div>
          ) : (
            <div key={Math.random()}>[OPTION2] show after onMouseLeave</div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: For me it works fine when I hover in/outside from right or left. From top/bottom its broken.

Comment: Only if the node doesn't follow the normal dom structure e.G postion: fixed top: 0 left: 0

Answer (score 16):

From the docs:

> The onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events propagate from the element
>   being left to the one being entered instead of ordinary bubbling and
>   do not have a capture phase.

Try to use onMouseOut, onMouseOver instead

```
<div onMouseOver={() => this.setState({ bool: true })} onMouseOut={() => this.setState({ bool: false })}>
  {
    this.state.bool ? (
      <span>[OPTION1] show after onMouseEnter</span>
    ) : (
      <div>[OPTION2] show after onMouseLeave</div>
    )
  }
</div>
```

Comment: @MoeSattler did you resolved this issue ? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: You must use `_.lodash` debounce if you don't want to trigger this a millions time.

Comment: Dimitri! After search internet for hours and questioning my sanity that was it! debounce slow it down other wise mouseOver will be called over and over

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I am newbie in React and please explain what do you meant by using `_.lodash`? I know there is [a lib](https://lodash.com/) with that name. but I doubt you meant it. Please provide more context and explanation. So newbies like me won't get confused